# Hints at why Emulator-Arm.exe is failing?

Tags: android-emulator

My project aimed at ICS/14 compiles, but won't run with the "Emulator-Arm.exe failed" err msg. Are these log msgs interesting to anybody:

[2011-11-02 20:46:14 - Emulator] goldfish_fb_load: framebuffer dimensions mismatch
[2011-11-02 20:46:14 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section goldfish_fb
[2011-11-02 20:46:19 - WhereAreYou] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.PterodactylsRUs.WhereAreYou.WhereAreYouActivity activity launch'!

?

Comment: Here's a clue, I think, on why the emulator works when I am using other AVDs, but with Ice Cream Sandwich I get the error: In my AVD Manager I see that the CPU/ABI column is the same for all of my AVDs ("ARM (armeabi)") except for ICS/4.0, which is ("ARM (armeabi-v7a)")